There exists a complex number $l$ with $A z=l z$ then how to prove that $A(\mathrm{i})=\mathrm{i} A(1)$?
For an $\mathbb{R}$-linear map
$$
A: \mathbb{C} \longrightarrow \mathbb{C}
$$
the following four statements are equivalent:

There exists a complex number $l$ with $A z=l z$.
$A$ is $\mathbb{C}$-linear.
$A(\mathrm{i})=\mathrm{i} A(1)$.

It is easy to see that 2,3 are equivalent and 2 implies 1 but how to prove that 1 implies 3?
$$ \left(
\begin{array} {c}
  a&b\\
  c&d
\end{array}
\right) \left(
\begin{array} {c}
  0\\
  1
\end{array}
\right)= (b+id) \ne i\left(
\begin{array} {c}
  a&b\\
  c&d
\end{array}
\right) \left(
\begin{array} {c}
  1\\
  0
\end{array}
\right)= (-c+ai)$$
So I don't know how would this work.

your matrix representation of the complex numbers makes no sense, there is no way to multiply 2 vectors in $\Bbb R^2$. Mixing the two representations by throwing an extra $i$ in there makes it even more confusing. You need to represent your numbers as $2\times2$ matrices, with $1\equiv\begin{pmatrix}1&0\0&1\end{pmatrix}$ and $i\equiv\begin{pmatrix}0&-1\1&0\end{pmatrix}$, so that the action of $A$ is written as $A(z) = AZA^{-1}$ where $Z$ is the matrix representation of $z$.

$1)$ implies $3)$:
$A(x+iy)=l(x+iy)=lx+ily$. In particular, $A(0+i(1))=l(0)+il(1)=il=iA(1)$.

How did you know that $A(1 )=l $ if $A(i)=il$? Why couldn't $A(i)= c \ne l$

By 1), $A(1)=(l)(1)=l$. @Mathematicsenjoyer

Can you explain more ? $A$ is $\mathbb{R}$- linear so $A(1)=l$ but how did you get $A(i )= i A(1)=il $from ?

$\mathbb R$ linearity of $A$ has no role to play in 1) implies 3).  I have just used 1) directly to get 3). You are just overthinking. @Mathematicsenjoyer

so 1 tells us that there is a constant $l$ that don't depend on $z$ such that $A(z)=lz$ for all $z$? or does $l$ depend on $z$?

It does not depend on $z$.

Property 1, which must be interpreted as "there exists $l$ such that for all $z$, $A(z)=lz$", immediately implies that $l=A(1)$ and hence further that $A(z)= A(1)\cdot z$ for any $z\in \mathbb C$.
